# i want to convert NSData To double value in Iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, types

i want covert content of NSData Which is actually i need as a double type 
   how can i convert  it?

here 
        1ff46c56 7dd86f40  nsdata byte and i want in double

Comment: Are you sure that NSData bytes are of a double value? How did you convert a double value into nsdata bytes? post some more code....

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assuming your data is exactly 8 bytes, you can convert it to a `double` using [`memcpy(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/memcpy):

```
double ConvertNSDataToDouble(NSData *data)
{
    double d;
    assert([data length] == sizeof(d));
    memcpy(&d, [data bytes], sizeof(d));
    return d;
}
```

Note that this assumes that the data is in native endian format.  If you know that the data is big- or little-endian, then you may need to endian-swap the bytes first.

Answer (score 6):

You can also do it like this (apart from *Adam Rosenfield's* answer).
This will work only if the data is UTF8 encoded.

```
NSString *dbleStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
double dble = [dbleStr doubleValue];
```

If the data is in endian format use one of the respective encoding formats from *NSUTF16BigEndianStringEncoding*, *NSUTF16LittleEndianStringEncoding*.

*Note: The data should contain a double value. Otherwise you will get unexpected results.*

Comment: That doesn't work at all for OP's example input of `1ff46c56 7dd86f40`.  Those bytes aren't valid UTF-8 characters, so `dbleStr` gets initialized with `nil`.

Comment: This will work only if the data is UTF8 encoded. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Solution with less overhead

```
const double *double_ptr = [data bytes];
```

Examples of use is simply:

```
double val = double_ptr[0]; // the first double value in array
```

or

```
double val = *double_ptr;
```